# Insert data into JSON column in postgres using JOOQ

Tags: json, postgresql, java-8, jooq

I have a postgres database to which I read/write using JOOQ. One of my DB tables has a column of type JSON. When I try to insert data into this column using the query below, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [update "public"."asset_state" set "sites_as_json" = ?]; ERROR: column "sites_as_json" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Below is the code for inserting data into the column

```
SiteObj s1 = new SiteObj();
s1.setId("1");
s1.setName("Site1");
s1.setGeofenceType("Customer Site");

SiteObj s2 = new SiteObj();
s2.setId("2");
s2.setName("Site2");
s2.setGeofenceType("Customer Site");

List<SiteObj> sitesList = Arrays.asList(s1, s2);
int result = this.dsl.update(as).set(as.SITES_AS_JSON, LambdaUtil.convertJsonToStr(sitesList)).execute();
```

The call LambdaUtil.convertJsonToStr(sitesList) outputs a string that looks like this...

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Site1","geofenceType":"Customer Site"},{"id":"2","name":"Site2","geofenceType":"Customer Site"}]
```

What do I need to do to be able to insert into the JSON column?

Comment: For anyone else wondering how to implement the `LambdaUtil.convertJsonToStr` function - you can use the Jackson or GSON packages, examples [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/kotlin-convert-json-to-object-jackson/#Convert_Object_to_JSON_StringFile) and [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/kotlin-parse-json-gson/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Current jOOQ versions

jOOQ natively supports `JSON` and `JSONB` data types. You shouldn't need to have to do anything custom.

#### Historic answer

For jOOQ to correctly bind your JSON string to the JDBC driver, you will need to implement a data type binding as documented here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

The important bit is the fact that your generated SQL needs to produce an explicit type cast, for example:

```
@Override
public void sql(BindingSQLContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    // Depending on how you generate your SQL, you may need to explicitly distinguish
    // between jOOQ generating bind variables or inlined literals.
    if (ctx.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED)
        ctx.render().visit(DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::json");
    else
        ctx.render().sql("?::json");
}
```

Comment: For the current version: please explain how it can be done with an example :)

Comment: @john: Nothing needs to be "done", so I can't give you an example. I don't know what you're missing. But you can ask a new, *specific* question.